# Cannot access a variable in a function within a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, global-variables

```
function updateRoomsList() {
    //empty the rooms list
    $("#rooms").empty();
    //fetch the non-joined rooms, id and name
    $.get('JoinPart', {
        goal: 5,
        userName: $("#userName").html()
    }, function (responseText) {
        var i = 0;
        id = "";
        while (i < responseText.length) {
            if (responseText.charAt(i) == '.') {
                //Now we got the full Id of a room, lets add it
                $.get('JoinPart', {
                    goal: 6,
                    roomId: id
                }, function (responseText) {
                    roomName = responseText;
                    $("#rooms").append('<div id="room' + id + '" class="listItem"><span title="Join Room" class="joinButton">+</span><div class="listItemContent">' + roomName + '</div></div>');
                });
                id = "";
            } else {
                id = id + responseText.charAt(i);
            }
            i++;
        }
    });
}
```

In this Function there's a variable `id`, if I `alert(id);` after

```
if(responseText.charAt(i)=='.')
```

I get the proper value of the id calculated in the `else` , but when I do `alert(id);` inside the `$.get` the id is empty `""` , means in the `append` function, the `id` has no value, how can I get this id to have the value outside of the $.get function ?

Comment: Have you tried declaring id outside of your updateRoomsList function: `var id;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `id` is scoped in the outer closure, so your inner callback gets a reference to the last value it's set at the end of the `while` loop. If you need a private copy of the `id` variable inside your second `$.get()` callback, you need to write

```
$.get('JoinPart', {goal :6, roomId :id }, (function (id) {
  return function (responseText) {
    roomName = responseText;
    $("#rooms").append('<div>' + id + '</div>');
  }
})(id));
```

When you do this, you create a new scope with a local variable `id` which is given the exact value `id` had at the current iteration, and not the local variable `id` itself, which at the end of the loop (or really just at the next iteration) could be anything.

The construct `(function(arg){})(arg)` is called an *[immediately invoked function expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)*. Please note that this function returns a new function object, the one required by `$.get()`

A *closure* is a function defined inside another one. A closure, by definition, can access all variables local to the outer function. When you supply a callback for later execution to `$.get()`, you are in fact using a closure: when the callback will be executed (possibly after several seconds) the JS engine will make `id` still accessible, but its value obviously depends on the rest of the code.

If you need to store the current snapshot of a variable for later reading, you need to create a new closure (ie a new scope): we use the IIFE for this purpose. The IIFE is executed right **before** the actual HTTP request is fired (ie **before** the `$.get()` is even called), and it's the nearest scope for the callback, so it will be used to resolve the `id` reference when the callback will be executed.

You can test if you understand the concept by figuring out what the following snippet will print

```
function inner() {
  console.log(i);          
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  inner();
  setTimeout(inner, 1000);
}​
```

Comment: OMG It worked!! Thanks a lot :D I love the answers that contains a fixed version of my codes, makes my day much better, I love you man :D

Answer (score 1):

Code flow is not the order you think.

```
            id="";
```

Is happening before the function-within-a-function, which is called a closure, by the way (this should help in your googling).  Add the print statements

```
alert("here 1");
alert("here 2");
```

in the closure, and before the `id="";` and this should jump out.

Easiest fix is probably to swap `id` with `roomId` in the closure, since, being a simple string or int, the value is fully copied to `roomId`, where it will be safe even if `id` changes (ok, more accurately, `id=...` only changes the reference so the value referred to by `roomId` stays the same.)